# features selection for large dataset in python

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, large-data, feature-selection

I have a Document-term matrix of dimension **3144469 x 268496** for which i need to do feature selection.I tried it doing with feature selection of Sckit-learn using code

```
fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=40)
documenttermmatrix_train= fs.fit_transform(documenttermmatrix,y1_train)
```

I am getting memory error

y1_train has around 9k unique values

**Is there any other function or library in python to do feature selection(chisquare,information gain) for large dataset in python?**

Comment: Is the matrix sparse or dense?

Comment: Sparse matrix...I am executing above code in system with 128GB RAM.....

Comment: How many not null values?